# AppBar is hiding my contents when i am adding scroll view of android

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-appbarlayout

I made an application to display my contents when the time am adding scroll view to my layout ,app bar is hiding the elements of layout [this is how my app looks like when i add scroll view in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOXKV.jpg) i dont want this , the reason why am added scroll view is i want to add more thing to it , please help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#fcfcfc"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/ll">


        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/bankcardId"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:focusable="true">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circlepurple"

                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Banking"/>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Check your bank activities"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:focusable="true">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circlepink"

                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Ideas"/>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Check your bank activities"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                </LinearLayout>
             </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

           </LinearLayout>
           <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:focusable="true">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circlegreen"

                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Add"/>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Check your bank activities"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:focusable="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circleyellow"
                        android:padding="10dp"></ImageView>


                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Links"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Check your bank activities"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

         </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="340dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:focusable="true">
                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circlepurple"

                        android:padding="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Add"/>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Check your bank activities"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i think you should wrap the whole *ScrollView* in a `FrameLayout` or any other layout. i'm not sure though, please try that and let me know if that works.

Comment: how will i do that ?

Comment: move whole `ScrollView` into `FrameLayout` tag